# Preserve old timestamp of file after editing

Tags: c++, c, winapi

How to preserve old timestamp after i change it ? 
i need to do this in win32 api

```
hfile = CreateFileA(path, //stackoverflow wont allow me submit this unless i include source ugghh >_<
                GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,
                FILE_SHARE_READ,
                NULL,
                OPEN_EXISTING,
                0,
                NULL);
```

Comment: Are you referring to the **Date Modified** or the **Date Accessed** time stamp?

Comment: both, so file will be like absolutely untouched

Answer (score 3):

You can call `SetFileTime` on the file handle like so:

```
FILETIME ft = { MAXDWORD, MAXDWORD };
SetFileTime(hFile, NULL, &ft, &ft);
```

This stops the system from modifying the timestamps when the file is written to.

Answer (score 2):

You can do so by calling [`GetFileTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) before you write the file and  and [`SetFileTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724933%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the original times to restore the file's previous timestamps.